# Add user in BuddyPress without using BuddyPress registration form

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I have a landing page with a call to action that points a user to a video and a quiz. The quiz is powered by a larger LMS, LearnDash.
LearnDash has the option to require the end user to enter information (fields are customization) before receiving their grade on the quiz.

When the user submits that information, I'd like to have it register them an account on the site. I'm not sure where to begin linking this process together.

I do know buddypress uses register.php to create an account,how do I hook that up to a button?

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the following three `hooks` to customize the registration form: **`register_form`**, **`registration_errors`**, & **`user_register`**.

> You can learn more about customizing the registration form in the **WordPress Codex** by visiting [this link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form).
>
> https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form

---

If using `hooks` is to complicated, there are a number of **WordPress** plugins available that make customizing the registration page a breeze.

[**RegistrationMagic**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-registration-form-builder-with-submission-manager/) - Plugin

**[Ultimate Member](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-registration-form-builder-with-submission-manager/)** - Plugin